# Accelerometer frequency stuck at 5 Hz

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-sensors

We are working on an app to record the vibration of a phone as part of a bigger project. Our goal is to record the accelerometer data and write it in a CSV file. We developed an app using Flutter and Dart. Till Android 12, the app was working as expected and we were getting accelerometer data at a defined frequency (100 Hz). However, after Android 13, Android phones provide a steady frequency of 5 Hz. If we request 100 Hz data, 5 data points are collected and duplicated 20 times each to make it look like 100 Hz.
We are using sensor plus and the code is provided below;

```
  //Start the accelerometer
  Future<void> _startAccelerometer() async {
    //Listen to gyroscope events
    _gyroSubscription = gyroscopeEvents.listen((event) {
      _gyroX = event.x;
      _gyroY = event.y;
      _gyroZ = event.z;
    });
    _accSubscription = accelerometerEvents.listen((sensorEvent) {
      setState(() {
        _accX = sensorEvent.x;
        _accY = sensorEvent.y;
        _accZ = sensorEvent.z;
      });

    });
```

In addition, we are trying Android native sensor library and the code is provided below;

```
import android.hardware.Sensor
import android.hardware.Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE
import android.hardware.SensorEvent
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener
import android.hardware.SensorManager

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity(), SensorEventListener {
    // this is channel
    private val CHANNEL = "com.example.cyroad_flutter/android_sensor"
    private val _eventValue = DoubleArray(6)

    // sensor list
    private lateinit var sensorManager: SensorManager
    // gyroscope Sensor
    private var gyroscopeSensor: Sensor? = null
    // accelerometer Sensor
    private var accelerometerSensor: Sensor? = null

    private fun getEventValue() : DoubleArray{
        return _eventValue
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event : SensorEvent?) {
        if (event != null) {
            if (event.sensor.type == gyroscopeSensor?.type){
                _eventValue[0] = event.values[1].toDouble()
                _eventValue[1] = event.values[2].toDouble()
                _eventValue[2] = event.values[3].toDouble()
            }
            if (event.sensor.type == accelerometerSensor?.type){
                _eventValue[3] = event.values[1].toDouble()
                _eventValue[4] = event.values[2].toDouble()
                _eventValue[5] = event.values[3].toDouble()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(p0: Sensor?, p1: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
```

We have tested the code with sensor plus library on iPhone and it worked fine. The constant issue we are getting from Android devices.